# Is there is a way to access Tooling API Objects in a test class

Tags: api, tooling

is there is a way to access **Tooling API Objects** ex.. **RemoteProxy**  in a test class? I am trying to create a **Test class** to check if a RemoteProxy record exists.

Sice test methods do not support Web service callouts the following code will fail

```
// Tooling API Call to receive IDs for all active FlowDefinitions
String toolingSOQL = '/services/data/v49.0/tooling/query?q=Select+Id,+EndpointUrl+From+RemoteProxy';
String baseURL     = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
String endpoint    = baseURL + toolingSOQL;
 
Http NewReq        = new Http();
HttpRequest hreq   = new HttpRequest();
 
hreq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
hreq.setTimeout(60000);
hreq.setEndpoint(endPoint);
hreq.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse hresp = NewReq.send(hreq);
 
String body = hresp.getBody();
System.debug('ResponseBody' + body);
```

Comment: No - callouts aren't allowed in a test class and there's no way to query RemoteProxy without a callout. If you change the implementation from a RemoteProxy or Remote Site to Named Credentials, you'll accomplish the same objective and be able to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Your unit test should use the [HttpCalloutMock Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_httpcalloutmock.htm) to return both positive and negative results, so you can test both paths (or however many you have). You should not be attempting to *actually* call the Tooling API, as you lose control over your test results.

Comment: I think I was not that clear in my description, My main issue is how do I query RemoteProxy object from a test class?

Comment: @Ihab You don't. Create a fake payload that returns the values your code expects.